# My zero values matter and case_when is removing them

Tags: r, case-when

I have a 2X2 design (it's more complex, but below a simple example to illustrate my issue).

Say my output data looks like this:

In the image, ID is each participant, block number is the condition they saw, and everybody saw 4 questions.

[image]

Where the counterbalancing plays a role (for example) is that the same item (e.g, Item1) was repeated in different positions between Q1-Q4 across participants depending on the block. In the picture above, Item1 would be the red numbers. I used case_when to pull out the combinations and give me a clean column of the Item1 responses:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(
  Item1= case_when(
    BlockNumber == 'Block1' & Q1 ~ Q1, 
    BlockNumber == 'Block5' & Q2 ~ Q2,
    BlockNumber == 'Block6' & Q3 ~ Q3,
    BlockNumber == 'Block7' & Q4 ~ Q4))
```

This gives me something like:

[image]
The code is doing exactly what I need it to, BUT the ZERO VALUES are getting dropped [highlighted in the picture].

Instead of a zero, it is just an NA value. Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orf28.png)

The problem is that zeros are meaningful in my data and I need to keep them.

Does anyone have an idea of what code I could add/use to avoid this? It really messes up my mean scores afterwards because the zeros are dropped.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of data. We can't easily copy/paste that into R for testing.

Comment: @VVO I think you misunderstand the problem. It's not 0 causing it, but your case when returns null for blocknumber greater than 4. you need to add more cases.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to say `Block5` to get the number in `Q2` that you have marked with red - is that not correct?

Comment: I still don't understand the question. In your top table screenshot, `BlockNumber` is a field with numbers in it from 1 to 8. Your tests check if any of those values in BlockNumber match text like 'Block1', which will always be false, since there aren't any values in that column of your table that have the word "Block" in them. I presume either the table of values or the code is not what you're using, otherwise I don't understand how it's working for you.

Comment: Sorry I just realized the picture doesn't accurately reflect my data. In my data, the BlockNumber column contains factors, "Block1" "Block2" "Block3". The issue as @William Gram picked up was that I was over specifying. All I needed was the BlockNumber== 'Block5' ~ Q1 to tell R where to get the value from. Yet, I was adding the extra bit of info with the &Q1 that was giving me a false, hence returning an NA.

Comment: Also to the rest of the commenters, apologies! I'll add a reproducible example in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason you are experiencing this is because the integer `0` evaluates to `FALSE`. That is, in the row where `BlockNumber == 'Block5'` you have that `Q2 == 0`, which means you are asking the case `BlockNumber == 'Block5' & FALSE` which is `FALSE`. Thus, you get NA for that case.

From your explanation it seems to me you don't actually need the second condition, so what you can do is to simplify your `case_when` operation:

```
data %>% mutate(
  Item1= case_when(
    BlockNumber == 'Block1' ~ Q1, 
    BlockNumber == 'Block5' ~ Q2,
    BlockNumber == 'Block6' ~ Q3,
    BlockNumber == 'Block7' ~ Q4))
```

At least I don't see why you would need the `& Qx` conditions. But let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much!!! That was exactly the issue. I thought I needed to over specify but I didn't need the & Qx, I get my zeroes now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- data %>% mutate(
  Item1= case_when(
    BlockNumber == 'Block1' & Q1 ~ Q1, 
    BlockNumber == 'Block4' & Q2 ~ Q2,
    BlockNumber == 'Block6' & Q3 ~ Q3,
    BlockNumber == 'Block7' & Q4 ~ Q4,

    # Get ready for some magic!
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

If you want to specify a value if the other tests haven't passed, you can use TRUE as your last "test" to use that value.

Otherwise, any case that doesn't pass the prior tests will output NA.